# PowerShell Start-Job Working Directory

Tags: powershell, start-job

Is there a way to specify a working directory to the Start-Job command?

Use-case:

I'm in a directory, and I want to open a file using Emacs for editing. If I do this directly, it will block PowerShell until I close Emacs. But using Start-Job attempts to run Emacs from my home directory, thus having Emacs open a new file instead of the one I wanted.

I tried to specify the full path using $pwd, but variables in the script block are not resolved until they're executing in the Start-Job context. So some way to force resolving the variables in the shell context would also be an acceptable answer to this.

So, here's what I've tried, just for completeness:

```
Start-Job { emacs RandomFile.txt }
Start-Job { emacs "$pwd/RandomFile.txt" }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A possible solution would be to create a "kicker-script":

```
Start-Job -filepath .\emacs.ps1 -ArgumentList $workingdir, "RandomFile.txt"
```

Your script would look like this:

```
Set-Location $args[0]
emacs $args[1]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked out really well. The -ArgumentList is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only work if `$workingdir` contains no spaces or other special characters.

Comment: @DiscoInfiltrator: Passing just `$workingdir` works fine in PowerShell, even with embedded spaces and other shell metacharacters (you're probably thinking of POSIX-like shells); verify with `$dir = 'C:\Program Files\'; function foo() { set-location $args[0] }; foo $dir`.

Comment: @Filburt, why do you call it "kicker-script"?

Comment: @Bowi That's really just personal naming thing - a script to kick off another script or executable.

Answer (score 37):

There is nice solution from [comments section of some dude's post](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2010/05/22/a-better-start-job-cmdlet/#comments). Commenter suggests to use `Init` parameter to setup working directory of script block.

```
function start-jobhere([scriptblock]$block) {
    Start-Job -Init ([ScriptBlock]::Create("Set-Location '$pwd'")) -Script $block
}
```

Comment: ++ for the most generic solution: no helper script needed, no input argument that the background script block needs to know about and handle.

Comment: this should have quotes around $pwd to handle spaces in the path

Comment: @ghostbust555 is correct, single quotes are needed because this is not a variable reference but a variable expansion in a string.

Comment: @Sander: Indeed (thanks for the correction - I'd missed that a _string_ is being constructed). There's a tiny chance that this will break, however, given that filenames may contain `'` instances, so a fully robust solution would be: `"Set-Location '$($pwd -replace "'", "''")'"`

Answer (score 17):

*Update*:

**PowerShell [Core] 7.0** brings the following **improvements**:

- Background jobs (as well as thread jobs and `ForEach-Object -Parallel`) now - sensibly - inherit the caller's current (filesystem) location.
- A new `-WorkingDirectory` parameter allows you to specify a directory explicitly.

---

To summarize the problem (applies to **Windows PowerShell** and **PowerShell Core 6.x**)

- **A background job started with `Start-Job` does *not* inherit the current location (working directory).**

  - It defaults to `$HOME\Documents` in Windows PowerShell, and `$HOME` in PowerShell Core.
  - If you're using **PowerShell *Core*** and you're targeting a file in the *current* directory, you can use the following, because the **new `... &` syntax by default runs the job in the *current* directory**:
    `emacs RandomFile.txt &`
- You cannot *directly* reference variables from the *current* session in a script block passed to `Start-Job`.

To complement [jdmichal's own helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2283489/45375) and [asavartsov's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17388991/45375), which still work well:

PSv3 introduced a simple way to reference the *current* session's variable values in a script block that is executed in a different context (as a background job or on a remote machine), via the `$using:` scope:

```
Start-Job { Set-Location $using:PWD; emacs RandomFile.txt }
```

Alternatively:

```
Start-Job { emacs $using:PWD/RandomFile.txt }
```

See [`about_Remote_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Variables)

---

Note:

- [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4530) reports the surprising inability to use `$using:` in the script block passed to `-InitializationScript`, even though it works in the main script block (the implied `-ScriptBlock` parameter).

  - `Start-Job -Init { Set-Location $using:PWD } { emacs RandomFile.txt } # FAILS`

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
Start-Job -inputobject $pwd -scriptblock { emacs "$input/RandomFile.txt" }
```

Here `$input` is predefined variable that internally take the value of `-inputobject` parameter

Answer (score 5):

Start-Job is an overkill for what you need (running a command in the background). Use **Start-Process** instead:

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow emacs RandomFile.txt
```

There are no issue with the current directory in this approach. I have also created a function to make this as simple as possible:

```
function bg() {Start-Process -NoNewWindow @args}
```

and then the invocation becomes:

```
bg emacs RandomFile.txt
```

This works on Windows 7 (Powershell v2).

Comment: But Start-Process persists after the terminal is closed?

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, here's the final script I implemented based on Filburt's answer, community-wiki style:

```
function Start-Emacs ( [string]$file )
{
    Start-Job -ArgumentList "$pwd\$file" { emacs $args[0] }
}
```