# powershell start-job doesn't do anything with scriptblocks

Tags: powershell, jobs

I'm trying to start a job that creates a file. But it doesn't.

here's the very simple code:

`start-job -ScriptBlock { "hi" | set-content "hi.txt" }`

The file "hi.txt" never gets created.

Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely creating the file, just not where you expect because you used a relative path.  Try executing this to see where the file is going:

```
Start-Job {$pwd} | Receive-Job -Wait
```

Better yet, use an absolute path:

```
Start-Job { 'hi' > c:\hi.txt }
```

Or pass in the desired path:

```
Start-Job {param($path) 'hi' > "$path\hi.txt"} -arg $pwd
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. 

This is broken behavior in my view. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224350/powershell-start-job-working-directory

Comment: I don't know about broken but it would be nice if `Start-Job` had a `WorkingDirectory` parameter.